# repeat values row by row until find changes

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have this table:

```
date        id    value
12/20/19    123   0
12/21/19    123   0
12/22/19    123   1
12/23/19    123   0
12/24/19    123   0
12/25/19    123   0
12/26/19    123   0
12/27/19    123   0
12/28/19    123   -1
12/29/19    123   0
12/30/19    123   0
12/31/19    123   0
12/20/19    563   0
12/21/19    563   0
12/22/19    563   0
12/23/19    563   0
12/24/19    563   1
12/25/19    563   0
12/26/19    563   0
```

I need to get something like this:

```
date        id    value
12/20/19    123   0
12/21/19    123   0
12/22/19    123   1
12/23/19    123   1
12/24/19    123   1
12/25/19    123   1
12/26/19    123   1
12/27/19    123   1
12/28/19    123   -1
12/29/19    123   -1
12/30/19    123   -1
12/31/19    123   -1
12/20/19    563   0
12/21/19    563   0
12/22/19    563   0
12/23/19    563   0
12/24/19    563   1
12/25/19    563   1
12/26/19    563   1
```

So, I need to repeat the value row by row until there is a change. Please notice I have to group by the date and the id.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Window Functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) to look at the next row value based on a group and change the data accordingly